# Apps won't install (silently fail after 100% downloaded)

Tags: google-play-store, installation, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

I have a problem with installing apps from Google Play onto my Samsung Galaxy S Plus phone.

It has Android 2.3.6. Yesterday I tried to download some apps. When I clicked 'Install', the app began to download but when it got to 100% it just disappeared and silently failed to install on my phone :\

I don't have an SD card and up to now I saved all my apps on the phone
and had no problems like this.
It seems to be some settings problem, but I don't know what to do.
any ideas?!

Comment: Do you have access to the device log (logcat)? That's sadly a chicken & egg problem (you'd need some additional app to see logs, e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat and attach the output from a failed install attempt to this question). That can also be done by installing the SDK and use the integrated log viewer from there, but that's not too straightforward.

Comment: Is there sufficient space available on your  phone to install the apps?

Comment: It sounds to me like the infamous /cache or /data/data out of space problem. I hope google addresses this issue and gives more space for these mounts. Usually there is plenty of room to install in /data/app, but the cache and data locations run out of room quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Someone already solved this without rooting the phone by uninstalling updates for Google Play Store app: Go to *Settings → Applications → All (tab)*, scroll down and tap "Google Play Store", then "Uninstall updates".

Source: [SamsungGalaxyForums](http://samsunggalaxysforums.com/showthread.php/9091-unable-to-download-install-update-any-apps-from-google-play-store)

Answer (score 1):

Its indeed quite possible that either the two directories residing on the filesystem, `/data/local/download` or `/cache/download` is probably full of temporary files and is not deleted which contributes to the symptoms of the app not installing after 100% downloaded.

Some ROMs do have this facility or feature in place, called `run-parts`, which is invoked by the `busybox` which does this clean up on boot to clear out the temporary downloaded files saved in the specified directories. Again, this is dependant on the ROM.

Maybe that's what you should try doing, *reboot to force the system to clean up the directories and try again upon bootup*?

If that fails, then it sounds likely that the `/cache` partition is very small not to hold the downloaded files. The trick employed by ROMs is this, the `/cache/download` is either sym-linked to `/data` on the `/data` partition. The other trick is that `/data/local/download` is re-binded to the `/cache/download` directory. (see this script below to see what the second trick is about)

```
#!/system/bin/sh
#
# bind mount /data/local/download to /cache/download if cache
# partition is too small
#

CACHESIZE=$(df /cache | tail -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2 | tr -d [:alpha:])
DATAONLY=$(getprop dalvik.vm.dexopt-data-only)
if [ $DATAONLY -eq 1 ]
then
  NEEDED=60000
else
  NEEDED=105000
fi

if [ $CACHESIZE -lt $NEEDED ]
then
  /system/xbin/busybox mount -o bind /data/local/download /cache/download
fi

rm /cache/download/downloadfile*.apk >/dev/null 2>&1

exit 0
```

Why `/cache` and `/data/local/download`? it is found in the ***init.rc*** script in the ramdisk of the ROM in question which has the following environment variables that tells the Google Play store, where to save the downloaded apps.

```
export ANDROID_CACHE /cache
export DOWNLOAD_CACHE /cache/download
```

The only thing I would suggest is to use File Explorer (just as I type this I realised yeah, root... but I digress), and clean out the directory manually for a start.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. When trying to install an app from the market, it would get to 100% download, then say download failed. Also, the same behavior occurred with updates to previously installed apps. Tried all sorts of things from various forms and nothing worked.

I am running Eclair, and decided that my phone was becoming a paperweight without these updates... So I resolved to install a new ROM, thankfully I did not have to go that far. I ran a one-click root application, and afterwards I could download updates and install new apps without issue.

Pretty sure rooting your phone will void the warranty, if that is not of concern and your at a dead end... perhaps give it try, it worked for me.

Comment: I'm sure there must be other solutions as well, apart from installing different ROM. I get similar problem sometimes on my HTC Desire but it works after some retry.

Answer (score 0):

Before uninstalling updates I would also  try Clear Data (same place - under Google Play in Application Manager). That fixed the same issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by going to App manager and uninstalling updates to Google Play. Things will download and install fine after.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a new incompatibility causing something similar (at least right now: May 2015).  Updates and reinstall of Facebook were repeatedly failing with "Package invalid" using both Google Play and 1Market.

It seems that the problem was my home program: Nova launcher.

This was on Bluestacks using my PC, by the way.

I changed my home program back to Gamepop-Home (the default that came with Bluestacks) and was able to install Facebook from the search box in Gamepop-Home.

Afterwards, I was able to go back to Nova Launcher and keep using Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Galaxy S(First Series) will easily handle 4.0 Kit to JB
Get the latest working galaxy toolkit, unlock the boot-loader:

Yes, You can uninstall updates for Google Play but that gimps your device.
How to: Links are hit or miss dead. Look up "Galaxy Tool Kit"

Those kits include step by steps.

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked for me and my phone is ZTE N9130 . I went to Google play and stopped the Sync updates. Then proceeded to downloading Apps on Google Play.  Also I made sure that I had on the Data and GPS button on. Everything continued to download in a matter of time. Yay!