# How can I load a Video Player App on my Nook Color without google play?

Tags: side-loading, nook-color

My son's nook color is incompatible with google play, and the default video player app wont play local video files I've uploaded to his nook's harddrive via usb-cable. How can I download a new video player app to his nook 'without' google play?

I am using software version 1.4.3 and am *not* interested in solutions that involve rooting the nook, or rolling back to a previous version of the software.

Comment: Do you have .apk of the "new video player"? If yes than just copy paste the .apk file to storage and using file explorer of nook run that .apk file in order to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing many different apps and many different *versions* of said apps, websites listing what apps work and what apps don't, and more than a few other things, I have reached the conclusion that, *You cannot load 3rd party video players on the Nook Color*. My reason for reaching this conclusion, is when I finally found an app and its correct version to work for the nook operating system, and used the correct working file manager app to run the .apk file the message my Nook Color gave me was;

> Install Blocked: For security reasons, only apps purchased through the NOOK Shop can be installed.

Comment: wait, read my answer before giving up

Answer (score 2):

- Download/get the `.apk` file of desired application.

  (Example: [MoboPlayer from this link](http://www.moboplayer.com/moboplayer_en.html).)
- Pass it to the android device.
- Use any `file explorer` to open this .apk file.
- Install the application.

Comment: I'm getting a message after the attempt that the app was unable to install...

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version of [MoboPlayer](http://www.moboplayer.com/moboplayer_en.html) take the .apk file, copy it to your NC, open the file through on NC and installed it.

Comment: My nook says that file is in an unsupported format.

Comment: Try to open the `apk` file from `File Manager` rather than Downloads list. Let me know if that does not work

Comment: I have to get a file manager that works from barnes and nobles, ill get back to you. currently the one I just tried is giving me issues. I think my [cache](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25295/apps-wont-install-silently-fail-after-100-downloaded) is full.

Comment: I'm getting a message after the attempt that the app was unable to install...

Answer (score 0):

if your smartphone can download this `new video player app` download it on your smartphone and then transfer `apk` file to your son's smartphone, using this application [share app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.for2w.appshare&hl=en).Best lucks..

Comment: I do not own any smartphones, this question is about a nook.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are unable to play those video I would recommend download [Mx Player](http://mx-video-player.en.softonic.com/android) from this link. and then copy it to your nook colors' sd card/storage. Then from the file manager of your nook, navigate to that **mx player.apk** file and click on it. It should prompt to install. Just install it. And play whatever you want. For any detailed information, like step by step procedure follow [this link](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/nook-color-faq/10388-how-manually-install-apps-nook-color.html)

hope that helps.

Comment: that link takes me to google play. This answer is not helpfull.

Comment: well then, wait for a while,till I get the direct download link. :)

Comment: here is [direct link](http://www.4shared.com/mobile/8pVvLq-J/MX_Player_Pro__177_.htm) for downloading mxplayer. hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information about good media player on Nook Color: http://drippler.com/barnes_noble/nook_color#!560253

You can try VLC nightly build for ARMv7:

http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/android-armv7/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://liliputing.com/2011/11/how-to-sideload-apps-on-the-nook-tablet-amazon-appstore-go-launcher-ex.html) you can enable app sideloading in the following way (text in *italics* is mine):

> **Enable unknown sources**
>
> There’s a hidden settings menu on the NOOK Tablet that lets you
>   install apps from unkown sources. You can’t get to it just by
>   navigating through the settings, but xda-developers forum member
>   lionclaw has provided an easy way to open the settings menu from your
>   web browser.
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> 1. Fire up the web browser and visit http://comptonsoft.com/test/
> 2. Click the <strike>“Download TGPS_launcher”</strike> link. *(They have changed it for "Download AppMenu" link, you can use this)*
> 3. You should see a notification in the lower left corner of your
>      device.
> 4. Click the notification and tap the entry that says **<strike>tgps_launcher.apk</strike> download complete**. *(Now it should mention AppMenu.apk)*
> 5. If you try to install the app using the Package Installer, you’ll be
>      whisked away to the screen shown above, where you can check the box
>      next to unknown sources.

Once you have enabled this option, you can follow the steps described in [Keshava's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/60326/12677)

---

### UPDATE:

> Fortunately/Unfortunately, the menu wasn't hard to find - all the user
>   had to do was to try to install an app from somewhere other than B&N's
>   app store voila! - the menu was triggered and the option could be
>   enabled. That lasted about a month. Calling the ability to find and
>   enable the option a "bug", B&N sent out an update that "fixed the
>   problem" shortly before Christmas. Ever since then, the only way you
>   can get non-B&N apps on the device is to either **root** it or use a
>   **dual-boot card**.

([Source](http://bookclubs.barnesandnoble.com/t5/NOOK-HD-HD-Support/Allowing-Unknown-Sources/m-p/1405682#M198))

Therefore, [your own answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/60466/12677) is the correct one. I'm sorry I couldn't help you to solve your problem as I would have liked.

Comment: I will attempt this, thank you for the first realistic answer this question has received. I will be in touch with news of my success or failure.

Comment: I'm afraid this method ends in the same result mentioned in the answer I posted, I receive the message that 3rd party apps cannot be installed. Is there another way to reach this menu?

Comment: I'm sorry to read that. Well, at least we tried. Let me research a little more about that, maybe there is something more we can do.

Comment: Unfortunately this option has been disabled by manufacturer. Read more details in an update I made to my answer.

Comment: Hey, I'm telling you because your the only user I've seen so far that has a realistic amount of rep, you guys seriously have moderation problems here. (Android.SE) I don't know how much staff (10k mods) you have here, or even regular users such as yourself, but I can say that in Arqade the nightmare that was this question never would have happened. Every single answer I got other than yours was basically the exact same thing. Your mods are slackin, HARD. Just wanna say, my experience here has been sub-par, I hope it's isolated to me.

Comment: @Ender Thanks for the bounty and for your nice words for me. The effort required to validate the answers that people post here in AE is shared between the moderators and us, regular users. Much of review activities don't provide reputation points (being just taken by true Android Enthusiasts), and as this site is for community, it is up to us to assume those tasks, only sending to moderators those posts which require special and additional efforts or privileges to be dealed with...

Comment: ... Because reputation is earned mainly by answering questions, some users just post one-line answers with links for the first Google results they find, showing a lack of research efforts. Maybe that doesn't happen in ArQAde because that is a site for gamers, and the research needed to answer correctly a question is made mainly by playing the games (it is the best kind of research, if you ask me), let's just say things are a bit different in AE. On the other hand, AE moderator activity is intense, as you will see in our [Meta](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com) site.