# Successfully download app 100% but wont install after that

Tags: google-play-store, 4.1-jelly-bean

I have a rooted mobile device (running Android 4.4). Whenever I download or update any app from *Google Play Store* it will show the download bar and reach till 100% – but won't install after that.

I have downloaded using WiFi and with enough space. Moreover, I have updated *Google Play Services* but not *Google Play Store.* I have tried all the solution like clear cache, force stop blah blah but yet there is a issue.

I've also read [Apps won't install (silently fail after 100% downloaded)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25295/16575) and checked its offered solutions. However my problem is a bit different that the one described there: After installing neither it throws an error stating "download failed" or "installing failed" nor it installs. Just stuck there for an hour unless and until WiFi gets disconnected. Sometime when it reach 100% it again starts itself to begin from 1% to download and so on.

Are there any other solutions I could try?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same problem. It get stuck at 100% and doesn't give any notifications.
Nexus 6p running Android 7.0 (not rooted).

After the app reaches 100% I close the play store (swipe it away from recent apps) and start it again, it'll install and download the next app and get stuck at 100% of the next app.

I am repeating the process to download the updates but it is by no means a fix to the problem. But atleast your apps will be updated.

Comment: I did what Temsah had done. after 100% closed play store on recent apps and restarted it. but the ap to be updated started all over from 1% again Im tired

Comment: Still works in 2019

Answer (score 1):

return your playstore to it's stock version, then update it to the current version. This will temporarily fix this installing issue, which I've been having as well. Other than that, I'm waiting in the same boat as you.

Answer (score -1):

after fully download wait 2 second, then restart the phone , you can see downloaded app is installing, temporary solved my problem,

my phn galaxy core duos androids v 4.2

Answer (score -3):

Clear Play Store from recent apps when it reach to 100% and then open Play Store once again it will install the app.

Comment: Don't advertise your own site unless it's directly related to the question.

Comment: You're welcome to mention your website *in [your profile](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/204844/jamil-shah), Jamil. But doing so in an answer without it being related to the topic is considered spamming, as Andy indicated.